# Making conclusions based on function output in idris

Tags: idris

Is there a way to draw a conclusion based on a the output of a function in Idris? For example let a function be defined as:

```
equalNumber: (x,y : Nat) -> Nat
equalNumber x y = case decEq x y of
                        Yes Refl => 42 
                        No contra => 0
```

Now i would really like to draw the conclusion that:

```
lemma : equalNumber x x = 42
```

Is this possible to prove? If it is: How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one solution:

```
total
lemma : equalNumber x x = 42
lemma {x} with (decEq x x)
  lemma {x} | (Yes Refl) = Refl
  lemma {x} | (No contra) = absurd $ contra Refl
```

Unfortunately, all my attempts to use `decEqSelfIsYes` lemma failed.

Comment: As @clayrat mentions in [issue #4394](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4394) one needs to change the definition of `equalNumber` to work around a bug in Idris.

Comment: Yes, at the moment you'd better avoid using `case` for the functions you later want to prove something about.